# Vector elements are indices of another vector Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 1x10 vector `A`

```
A = [11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 111]
```

Each value in `A` represents an index in vector `B` which is 1x200.

I want to get each value in vector `A` and go to the index of this value in vector `B` and get the value of this index and the 10 items before and 10 items after.

For example, the first element in vector `A` is 11, so I'll go to index 11 in vector `B` and get the value of this index (11th value) and the value of the 10 items before it (from 1 to 10) and 10 items after (from 12 to 21), same for every element in `A`.

Is possible to do it without loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is on using `bsxfun`

```
R = B(bsxfun(@plus, A(:), -10:10));
```

now row `n` in `R` contains the elements corresponding to element `n` in `A`. If you want it in a vector use:

```
R = reshape(B(bsxfun(@plus, A(:), -10:10)), 1, []);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! and if I want R to be of size Nx21 in a row?

Comment: @user1460166 then replace `1, []` with `[], 21`

Answer (score 0):

The straight-forward way, with the loop.
How fast do you need it? Is a simple loop approach not fast enough?

```
C = zeros(21, length(A))
for k = 1:length(A)
    C(:,k) = (-10:10)' + A(k);
end
C = C(:);

B(C)    # returns the elements you seek
```